# unable to get thread context of an suspended process'

Tags: python, ctypes

so, i am trying to write a script in python by which i can get the different register's value of a thread as well as also get the imagebase address and other different values which are related to process's PEB header. till now i wrote script by which i can create a process in suspended mode and passing the thread handle to GetThreadContext() function, but it returns ebx register's value 0.
i've tried context structure for both x86 and x64 but no luck.

here is the code snippet:

```
from ctypes import *
from ctypes.wintypes import *
import os,sys

target_exe = 'c:\\windows\\system32\\calc.exe'

LPDWORD = POINTER(DWORD)
LPHANDLE = POINTER(HANDLE)
ULONG_PTR = POINTER(ULONG)

class SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("nLength", DWORD),
                ("lpSecurityDescriptor", LPVOID),
                ("bInheritHandle", BOOL)]
LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES = POINTER(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES)
DWORD64 = c_ulonglong

CONTEXT_AMD64           = 0x00100000
CONTEXT_CONTROL         = (CONTEXT_AMD64 | 0x00000001)
CONTEXT_INTEGER         = (CONTEXT_AMD64 | 0x00000002)
CONTEXT_SEGMENTS        = (CONTEXT_AMD64 | 0x00000004)
CONTEXT_FLOATING_POINT  = (CONTEXT_AMD64 | 0x00000008)
CONTEXT_DEBUG_REGISTERS = (CONTEXT_AMD64 | 0x00000010)
CONTEXT_MMX_REGISTERS   = CONTEXT_FLOATING_POINT
CONTEXT_FULL = (CONTEXT_CONTROL | CONTEXT_INTEGER | CONTEXT_FLOATING_POINT)
CONTEXT_ALL = (CONTEXT_CONTROL | CONTEXT_INTEGER | CONTEXT_SEGMENTS |
                CONTEXT_FLOATING_POINT | CONTEXT_DEBUG_REGISTERS)
CONTEXT_EXCEPTION_ACTIVE    = 0x0000000008000000
CONTEXT_SERVICE_ACTIVE      = 0x0000000010000000
CONTEXT_EXCEPTION_REQUEST   = 0x0000000040000000
CONTEXT_EXCEPTION_REPORTING = 0x0000000080000000

class M128A(Structure):
    _fields_ = [
            ("Low", DWORD64),
            ("High", DWORD64)
            ]

class XMM_SAVE_AREA32(Structure):
    _fields_ = [
                ('ControlWord', WORD),
                ('StatusWord', WORD),
                ('TagWord', BYTE),
                ('Reserved1', BYTE),
                ('ErrorOpcode', WORD),
                ('ErrorOffset', DWORD),
                ('ErrorSelector', WORD),
                ('Reserved2', WORD),
                ('DataOffset', DWORD),
                ('DataSelector', WORD),
                ('Reserved3', WORD),
                ('MxCsr', DWORD),
                ('MxCsr_Mask', DWORD),
                ('FloatRegisters', M128A * 8),
                ('XmmRegisters', M128A * 16),
                ('Reserved4', BYTE * 96)
                ]

class DUMMYSTRUCTNAME(Structure):
    _fields_=[
              ("Header", M128A * 2),
              ("Legacy", M128A * 8),
              ("Xmm0", M128A),
              ("Xmm1", M128A),
              ("Xmm2", M128A),
              ("Xmm3", M128A),
              ("Xmm4", M128A),
              ("Xmm5", M128A),
              ("Xmm6", M128A),
              ("Xmm7", M128A),
              ("Xmm8", M128A),
              ("Xmm9", M128A),
              ("Xmm10", M128A),
              ("Xmm11", M128A),
              ("Xmm12", M128A),
              ("Xmm13", M128A),
              ("Xmm14", M128A),
              ("Xmm15", M128A)
              ]


class DUMMYUNIONNAME(Union):
    _fields_=[
              ("FltSave", XMM_SAVE_AREA32),
              ("DummyStruct", DUMMYSTRUCTNAME)
              ]

class CONTEXT64(Structure):
    _fields_ = [
                ("P1Home", DWORD64),
                ("P2Home", DWORD64),
                ("P3Home", DWORD64),
                ("P4Home", DWORD64),
                ("P5Home", DWORD64),
                ("P6Home", DWORD64),
                ("ContextFlags", DWORD),
                ("MxCsr", DWORD),
                ("SegCs", WORD),
                ("SegDs", WORD),
                ("SegEs", WORD),
                ("SegFs", WORD),
                ("SegGs", WORD),
                ("SegSs", WORD),
                ("EFlags", DWORD),
                ("Dr0", DWORD64),
                ("Dr1", DWORD64),
                ("Dr2", DWORD64),
                ("Dr3", DWORD64),
                ("Dr6", DWORD64),
                ("Dr7", DWORD64),
                ("Rax", DWORD64),
                ("Rcx", DWORD64),
                ("Rdx", DWORD64),
                ("Rbx", DWORD64),
                ("Rsp", DWORD64),
                ("Rbp", DWORD64),
                ("Rsi", DWORD64),
                ("Rdi", DWORD64),
                ("R8", DWORD64),
                ("R9", DWORD64),
                ("R10", DWORD64),
                ("R11", DWORD64),
                ("R12", DWORD64),
                ("R13", DWORD64),
                ("R14", DWORD64),
                ("R15", DWORD64),
                ("Rip", DWORD64),
                ("DebugControl", DWORD64),
                ("LastBranchToRip", DWORD64),
                ("LastBranchFromRip", DWORD64),
                ("LastExceptionToRip", DWORD64),
                ("LastExceptionFromRip", DWORD64),
                ("DUMMYUNIONNAME", DUMMYUNIONNAME),
                ("VectorRegister", M128A * 26),
                ("VectorControl", DWORD64)
]

SIZE_OF_80387_REGISTERS     = 80
MAXIMUM_SUPPORTED_EXTENSION = 512





class FLOATING_SAVE_AREA(Structure):
    _pack_ = 1
    _fields_ = [
        ('ControlWord',     DWORD),
        ('StatusWord',      DWORD),
        ('TagWord',         DWORD),
        ('ErrorOffset',     DWORD),
        ('ErrorSelector',   DWORD),
        ('DataOffset',      DWORD),
        ('DataSelector',    DWORD),
        ('RegisterArea',    BYTE * SIZE_OF_80387_REGISTERS),
        ('Cr0NpxState',     DWORD),
    ]
PFLOATING_SAVE_AREA = POINTER(FLOATING_SAVE_AREA)
LPFLOATING_SAVE_AREA = PFLOATING_SAVE_AREA
    
class CONTEXT(Structure):

    _fields_ = [

        ('ContextFlags',        DWORD),
        ('Dr0',                 DWORD),
        ('Dr1',                 DWORD),
        ('Dr2',                 DWORD),
        ('Dr3',                 DWORD),
        ('Dr6',                 DWORD),
        ('Dr7',                 DWORD),
        ('FloatSave',           FLOATING_SAVE_AREA),
        ('SegGs',               DWORD),
        ('SegFs',               DWORD),
        ('SegEs',               DWORD),
        ('SegDs',               DWORD),
        ('Edi',                 DWORD),
        ('Esi',                 DWORD),
        ('Ebx',                 DWORD),
        ('Edx',                 DWORD),
        ('Ecx',                 DWORD),
        ('Eax',                 DWORD),
        ('Ebp',                 DWORD),
        ('Eip',                 DWORD),
        ('SegCs',               DWORD),         # MUST BE SANITIZED
        ('EFlags',              DWORD),         # MUST BE SANITIZED
        ('Esp',                 DWORD),
        ('SegSs',               DWORD),
        ('ExtendedRegisters',   BYTE * MAXIMUM_SUPPORTED_EXTENSION),
    ]


class PROCESS_INFORMATION(Structure):
    _fields_ = [
                ('hProcess', c_void_p), 
                ('hThread', c_void_p), 
                ('dwProcessId', c_ulong), 
                ('dwThreadId', c_ulong)]

    

class STARTUPINFO(Structure):
    _fields_ = [
                ('cb', c_ulong), 
                ('lpReserved', c_char_p),    
                ('lpDesktop', c_char_p),
                ('lpTitle', c_char_p),
                ('dwX', c_ulong),
                ('dwY', c_ulong),
                ('dwXSize', c_ulong),
                ('dwYSize', c_ulong),
                ('dwXCountChars', c_ulong),
                ('dwYCountChars', c_ulong),
                ('dwFillAttribute', c_ulong),
                ('dwFlags', c_ulong),
                ('wShowWindow', c_ushort),
                ('cbReserved2', c_ushort),
                ('lpReserved2', c_ulong),    
                ('hStdInput', c_void_p),
                ('hStdOutput', c_void_p),
                ('hStdError', c_void_p)]

LPSTARTUPINFO = POINTER(STARTUPINFO)
LPPROCESS_INFORMATION = POINTER(PROCESS_INFORMATION)
LPCONTEXT = POINTER(CONTEXT64)
kernel32 = WinDLL('kernel32', use_last_error=True)
#process_id = os.getpid()
try:

    CREATE_SUSPENDED = 0x00000004
    startupinfo = STARTUPINFO()
    startupinfo.cb = sizeof(STARTUPINFO)
    processinfo = PROCESS_INFORMATION()

    kernel32.CreateProcessA.argtypes = [LPCSTR,LPSTR,LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES,LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES,BOOL,DWORD,LPVOID,LPCSTR,LPSTARTUPINFO,LPPROCESS_INFORMATION]
    kernel32.CreateProcessA.restype = BOOL
    if not kernel32.CreateProcessW(None,
                            target_exe,
                            None,
                            None,
                            True,
                            0x00000004,
                            None,
                            None,
                            byref(startupinfo),
                            byref(processinfo)):
            #kernel32.GetLastError()
            print ("Process creation [!]Error: " + FormatError(GetLastError()))
    #print(processinfo)
    hProcess = processinfo.hProcess
    hThread = processinfo.hThread
    print('process :',hProcess, ' thread: ',hThread)
    print('process_id :',processinfo.dwProcessId , 'thread_id :',processinfo.dwThreadId)

    
    if hProcess:
        print('handle created')
        kernel32.GetThreadContext.argtypes = [c_void_p,c_void_p]
        kernel32.GetThreadContext.restypes = c_uint

        cx = CONTEXT()
        cx2 = CONTEXT64()
        cx.ContextFlags = CONTEXT_FULL 
        cx2.ContextFlags = CONTEXT_FULL
        
        if kernel32.GetThreadContext(hThread, byref(cx)) == 0:
                print ("[!]Error: " + FormatError(GetLastError))
        
        print(cx, cx.Ebx, cx.Eax, cx.Edx, cx.Edi, cx.Ebp)

        if kernel32.GetThreadContext(hThread, byref(cx2)) == 0:
                print ("[!]Error: " + FormatError(GetLastError))
        
        print(cx2, cx2.Rbx, cx2.Rax, cx2.Rdx, cx2.Rdi, cx2.Rbp)


        kernel32.CloseHandle(hProcess)
    else:
        GetLastError()
        print('bad luck!!!')
        sys.exit()
    print('end of process')
    sys.exit()
except Exception as e:
    print(str(e))
    pass
```

output:

```
process : 476  thread:  472
process_id : 9116 thread_id : 9068
handle created
<__main__.CONTEXT object at 0x0000023604ACC640> 0 0 0 0 0
<__main__.CONTEXT64 object at 0x0000023604ACC6C0> 0 0 876891295744 0 0
end of process
```

for x64 structure, only getting the value of Rdx. for x86 structure everything is 0.
here is the screenshot of the output:
([screenshot of output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zr4Ds.png))

could you guys tell me what is actually happening wrong or what i'm doing wrong.

**i know that it is comparatively easier to do in c++ but i really want to do in python, for much more better understanding of ctypes and grasp on ctypes.
i did lots of googling and trail run but no luck till now.

testing environment: win 10.0.18363 N/A Build 18363 64bit vbox machine

thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: Lots of code (there might be a typo (`kernel32.GetThreadContext.restypes = c_uint` - it's ***restype***) or something wrong somewhere). Does it work from *C*?

Comment: @CristiFati thanks for highlighting the typo. I changed that to restype. but still no luck. getting every value 0. I've tried using c++ and it's working fine (at least not getting 0)

Comment: I suggest you improve your question, add some examples, some code and make it more clear, Have a look here => [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @Soumik Mondol the question is very well asked but you should add the non correct output or error so that people can help you better

Comment: A running process is either 32 or 64 bits. So, getting both contexts is wrong as one will be *WoW* (different structures (names), didn't check if they're actually different). You get some data for *64bit* because *Python* is *64bit*.

Comment: @FedericoBaù I've attached the screenshot of the output after the code section. **[Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zr4Ds.png) **

Comment: @CristiFati yes.. I need 64 bits version. But 64 bits also give me only value of rdx, rests are 0. But I need value of ebx. There may be something wrong in the structure definition. That I want to know what is actually wrong

Comment: @Soumik Mondol I see it know, I also suggest you to add it as a text, not as a picture. Among the reason the first three:  1. People May not see it (like me :P) .2 Is difficult for other users to troubleshooting, they may need to copy the error code for whatever reason. .3 The error code won't show up on Google Search because is a picture, Actually you should add it in the title (part of the error code), you may help someone in the future !

Comment: @FedericoBaù ok (Y)... So am getting this output:

process : 292  thread:  272

process_id : 11744 thread_id : 8332

handle created

<__main__.CONTEXT object at 0x000002671645C640> 0 0 0 0 0

<__main__.CONTEXT64 object at 0x000002671645C6C0> 0 0 221885788160 0 0

end of process

Comment: @SoumikMondol :)  I meant in your question, you can edit the question and add the error code nicely. :)

Comment: Run your code without CREATE_SUSPENDED.  If you are suspended at the entry point of the process registers might not be completely set up.  I do get other values in CONTEXT64.  Also, `lpReserved2` in STARTUPINFO should be `LPBYTE` (different size than c_ulong in 64-bit), and CreateProcessA argtypes/restype were defined, but CreateProcessW was called.  Make sure to define the appropriate STARTUPINFO A or W version as needed.

Comment: @MarkTolonen Thanks for the corrections. Yes. If I start a process without CREATE_SUSPENDED then am getting non-zero values. But I also tried using cpp. Using cpp even if I create process with CREATE_SUSPENDED then also it returns non-zero values(tried in vs2017).